# Multiple POST SQL injection from same IP

Tags: apache-2.2, security, centos6, sql

Recently I checked my Apache domlog and noticed the following attack:

```
POST /index.php?page=shop.item_details&cat_id=150&flp=flp_images.tpl&prod_id=9191&vmcchk=1&option=com_vm&Itemid=999999.9)+%2f**%2fuNiOn%2f**%2faLl+%2f**%2fsElEcT+0x393133359144353632312e39,0x393133358134383632322e39...
```

which is an obvious attempt at SQL injection.  This proceeded to occur around 3000 times from the same IP.  Now I could blacklist this IP but are there some better rules to apply to prevent things like this from occuring server side?

This server is running CentOS 6.4

Comment: Edited out the duplicate side question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Community, base [core rule](http://www.modsecurity.org/documentation/ModSecurity_Core_Rules.pdf) set included with [modsecurity](http://www.modsecurity.org/) will detect and block these requsts based on string (like if it contains select and union and from) or according to scores, or frequency etc. Depends on how you want to configure it.

Example file: https://github.com/SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs/blob/master/base_rules/modsecurity_crs_41_sql_injection_attacks.conf